# While loop and setInterval()

Tags: javascript, while-loop, setinterval

I am trying to mix the initial string and randomly compare the string's elements with the right elements on the right indexes, and if true push them into a set, to reconstruct the initial string. Doing this I met the problem that while loop does nothing just crushng the browser. Help me out with this.

```
function checker() {
  var text = document.getElementById("inp").value;
  var a = [];
  var i = 0;

  while (a.length < text.length) {
    var int = setInterval((function() {
      var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length);
      if (text[rnd] === text[i]) {
        a.push(text[rnd]);
        clearInterval(int);
        i++;
      }
    }), 100)
  }
}
```

P.S. I need the setInterval() function because I need the process to happen in exactly the same periods of time.

Comment: The problem is that you are not even getting to the second i. Why? Because you're still in the interval function which never ends. You should clear the interval somewhere else. I honestly have no idea what you should do in this case. I hope this helps though.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Legionar I am trying to create exactly the same string by randomly mixing the initial. AndI want it to be done with setinterval and while loop

Comment: @blitzar787 See my answer, and demo. Its doing exactly what you want - creating exactly the same string by randomly mixing the initial, and also using `setInterval`. You didnt write where you want the result, so you have it written in the console and also in another input field with id `output_string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you stumbled into the pitfall most people hit at some point when they get in touch with asynchronous programming.

You cannot "wait" for an timeout/interval to finish - trying to do so would not work or block the whole page/browser. Any code that should run after the delay needs to be called from the callback you passed to `setInterval` when it's "done".

In my answer its doing exactly what you want - creating exactly the same string by randomly mixing the initial, and also using `setInterval`. You didn't write where you want the result, so you have it written in the console and also in another input field with id `output_string`.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="input_string" value="some_text" />
<input id="output_string" value="" readonly="readonly" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function checker() {
    var text = document.getElementById("input_string").value;
    var result = '';

    // split your input string to array
    text = text.split('');

    var int = setInterval((function() {
        var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length);

        // add random character from input string (array) to the result
        result += text[rnd];

        // remove used element from the input array
        text.splice(rnd, 1);

        // if all characters were used
        if (text.length === 0) {
            clearInterval(int);

            console.log(result);

            document.getElementById("output_string").value = result;
        }
    }), 100);
}

checker();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/legionar/gprb49pv/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I have no idea what you are trying to do here, but you seem to have lost track of how your code is operating exactly.

All your while loop does, is creating the interval, which is ran asynchronous from the loop itself.
In other words, the only way your `while` condition equates to false, **is after multiple 100ms intervals have elapsed**. 100 miliseconds is an eternity when comparing it to the speed of 1 loop iteration. We're looking at 1000s of iterations before your first `setInterval` even triggers, not something a browser can keep up with, let alone wait several of these intervals before you change `a.length`.

Try more like this:

```
function checker() {
  var text = document.getElementById("inp").value;
  var a = [];
  var i = 0;

  // start to do a check every 100ms.
  var interv = setInterval(function() {
      var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length);
      if (text[rnd] === text[i]) {
        a.push(text[rnd]);
        i++;
      }

      // at the end of each call, see if a is long enough yet
      if(a.length > text.length){
        clearInterval(interv); // if so, stop this interval from running
        alert(a); // and do whatever you need to in the UI.
      }
    }, 100);
  }
}
```